# Maximum likelihood estimate of square root of mean of geometric population

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, geometric-distribution, transform, invariance

We have $n$ independently geometrically distributed values: $X_{1}, X_{2}, ... $ IID ~ Geom(p)

We also assume that $n$ data values $x_{1}, x_{2},...$ are available.

Now I would like to find the MLE estimate of the square root of the mean.

I worked through the problem and found the MLE of the *mean* to be $\frac{1}{\bar{ X}}$.

Is there a relationship here I should know about here?

Comment: Hint: invariance - please also add the self-study tag.

Answer (score 1):

Maximum likelihood estimation has a property of functional invariance --

The MLE of $g(\theta)$, $\widehat{g(\theta)} = g(\widehat{\theta})$, where $\hat{\theta}$ is the MLE of $\theta$.

[If you consider monotonic transformations - as you have here - then this should be instantly obvious, because monotonic transformation preserves the ordering of values of the likelihood function. But the result is more general.]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Functional_invariance